# Resolve SVN Conflict

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, command-prompt, finalbuilder

We are taking svn update through command line in Final Builder. Sometimes svn gets conflict in source. We need resolve this conflict.

How to resolve this svn Conflict using the final builder or command prompt ?

Answer (score -1):

TortoiseSVN is a very handy tool for COnflict resolution which gives you a good UI to compare the source
Pls. read that info here : https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html

Comment: Thanks for comments . I have already read this page . Following argument i passed in TortoiseSVN. But source are not changed.  Argument : svn resolve --accept theirs-full

Comment: Not sure, why it was voted -1 , as that was the suggestion I could give based on the problem statement in the first instance